# How to reduce logic expressions?

Tags: c++, logic, boolean-logic

```
{
ans += (a[i] > a[j]) != (b[i] > b[j]);
//ans += ((a[i] > a[j]) && (b[j] > b[i])) || ((a[j] > a[i]) && (b[i] > b[j]));
}
```

What you see above is a snippet I took from some where. There are two logic expressions. Supposedly, the one commented out is the same as the one not commented out.

How do you get from:

```
((a[i] > a[j]) && (b[j] > b[i])) || ((a[j] > a[i]) && (b[i] > b[j]))
```

to something like this

```
(a[i] > a[j]) != (b[i] > b[j])
```

Are there any guides or books for these kind of logic expression simplifications?

Comment: You don't need books on that when you have [Google](https://www.google.co.il/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=boolean+logic)!

Comment: actually, i don't think they are equivalent.  the way i imagine a proof working would be based on the right-hand conditions being negations of the left hand, and they are not (consider equality).

Comment: i think the conversion is wrong. if a[i] == a[j] and b[i] > b[j], the first logic returns false while the second returns true.

Comment: Supposing equality is impossible, you could imagine it like this: `(A & !B) | (!A & B)` is changed to `A xor B`.

Comment: Sometimes it is easiest to get out the pen and paper and solve some instances with play data. This way you get a feel for whats happening then you can abstract it back to a formula.

Comment: Logic is logic. If you crack the thought process deciphering the code meaning will be simple. And NEVER assume that something commented out means that it is equivalent to the line above or below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is right if you assume that

```
!(p > q) == (p < q)
```

Meaning that for some reason, you're ignoring equality.

With this in mind, let's say that:

```
a1 = a[i]
a2 = a[j]
b1 = b[i]
b2 = b[j]
```

Then you have:

```
ans += ((a1 > a2) && (b2 > b1)) || ((a2 > a1) && (b1 > b2));
```

Which, since we're ignoring equality, is the same as:

```
ans += ((a1 > a2) && !(b1 > b2)) || (!(a1 > a2) && (b1 > b2));
```

If you take a closer look, you'll see that the expressions are repeated, so they can be simplified:

```
A = a1 > a2
B = b1 > b2
```

Then:

```
ans += (A && !B) || (!A && B);
```

Which means **either A or B, but no both**
This is a known boolean operation called **[XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR)**, which in your case is the same as **different** (!=)

Therefore:

```
ans += A != B;
```

And expanding:

```
ans += (a1 > a2) != (b1 > b2)
```

So:

```
ans += (a[i] > a[j]) != (b[i] > b[j])
```

Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple.

With `(a[i] > a[j]) != (b[i] > b[j])`, what we're saying is that this will only be true when the relationship to `a[i]` and `a[j]` is the opposite of the relationship from `b[i]` to `b[j]`. For this to hold then, if `a[i]>a[j]` is true, then `b[i]>b[j]` is false, which means that `b[j]>b[i]` is true. This means that when `a[i]>a[j]` is true, `b[j]>b[i]` is true, and it also means the inverse - when `a[j]>a[i]` is true, then `b[i]>a[j]` as well.

Another way of saying all of that is `( (a[i]>a[j]) && (b[j]>a[i]) ) || ( (a[j]>a[i]) && (b[i]>b[j])`  . That boolean logic will be true only in the same cases where `( (a[i] > a[j]) ) != (b[i] > b[j])` is true.

As another example, consider when both `a[i] > a[j]`  and `b[i] > a[j]`  . You'll see that the first you posted is false in this condition, because the two terms on either side of the `!=` evaluate to true, meaning the `!=` evaluates to `false`. This case also causes the second statement to resolve to false because you don't have either of the two terms around the `||` evaluating to true, they both evaluate to false.

Lastly, this question looks like homework to me - if it is you should use the appropriate tag.

However, this all ignores the possibilities of `a[i] == a[j]` or `b[i] == b[j]`, which another answer to this question demonstrates can cause the two statements to not evaluate to the same thing. But if you assume that the two cannot be equal, then the two statements from your question will be the same, following the logic demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

These expressions are not equivalent.

For example, when `a[i] == a[j]` and `b[i] > b[j]`, the first expression gives...

```
(a[i] > a[j]) != (b[i] > b[j]);
false != true
true
```

...while the second one gives:

```
((a[i] > a[j]) && (b[j] > b[i])) || ((a[j] > a[i]) && (b[i] > b[j]));
(false && false) || (false && true)
false || false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this:

```
((a[i] > a[j]) && (b[j] > b[i])) || ((a[j] > a[i]) && (b[i] > b[j]))
```

and call it this, for simplicity:

```
(w > x) && (y > z) || (x > w) && (z > y)
```

which is NOT logically equivalent to:

```
(w > x) && (y > z) || !(w > x) && !(y > z)
```

because they could be equal, but it is to:

```
(w > x) && (y > z) || !(w >= x) && !(y >= z)
```

So you could simplify it to `(w > x) == (y > z)` or, alternatively, to `(w > x) != (z >= y)`.